# Averaging specific range of data with loop in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, database, reduce

I have a temperature data taken in every second (1Hz).

[image]

I want to reduce this data to minutes combined with averaging every 60 seconds of data. Which will be look like this.

[image]

I have tried moving average and other things but it didn't work. Is there any VBA code that i can approach my goal or any spesific function.

My time data range is [A3] - [A88739] and data range is [B3] to [B99739]

I will be waiting for your answers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think easier way would be using a helper column.

This will work only if your time data is always like the one you've posted and if the last 6 chars are `.XXXXX` where `X` can be letter or numbers, but leading dot is critical

[image]

My formula in column C is `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A3;LEN(A3)-6);".";"/"))`

Then with Pivot Table you can group your data by day,hour and minute, and get the average.

Setup of My Pivot Table:

1. Field `Helper` into rows section, and grouped by days, hours and minutes
2. Field `Temp` into values section, and choose average instead of sum up

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried the pivot table but couldn't get the filters as hours,minutes and days. Now it works perfectly i have managed to filter those values just as i want!